# How can I access node's util functions from within spookyJS?

Tags: node.js, spookyjs

I'm struggling to get node's util functions to output anything from within a spookyJS callback:

```
var utils = require('utils');
...spooky code...
spooky.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    utils.log('message'); // does nothing
    this.utils.log('message'); // does nothing
}
```

Is it possible to access the util functions within a callback like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that you are trying to require `utils` instead of `util`.

Comment: gah, that was it! Thanks :)

Comment: It happens to everyone :) Glad I could help!